# How to create only one procedure that change the backcolor of whatever label that clicked?

Tags: vb.net

Guys, say I have 3 labels named "lblTest1", "lblTest2", and "lblTest3". All labels have same backcolor, which is black.

```
lblTest1.BackColor = Color.Black
lblTest2.BackColor = Color.Black
lblTest3.BackColor = Color.Black
```

Now I want to change the backcolor of the labels to red when clicked so I need 3 different procedures for each event.

```
Private Sub lblTest1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblTest1.Click
       lblTest1.BackColor = Color.Red
End Sub


Private Sub lblTest2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblTest2.Click
       lblTest2.BackColor = Color.Red
End Sub


Private Sub lblTest3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblTest3.Click
       lblTest3.BackColor = Color.Red
End Sub
```

What I'm trying to do is to create **only one** subfunction that change the backcolor of **whatever label that clicked** to colors.red. Is it possible to do this? Can you explain it to me, please? Because currently I'm working with at least 300 labels right now, and not only change its color but other actions as well, so the solutions for this will be so much helpful. :)

Comment: `sender` is the target object of the event, so you can pass it to a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle multiple events in the same sub, like this:

```
Private Sub label_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   
        lblTest1.Click, lblTest2.Click, lblTest3.Click
```

To get the label that was clicked, use the sender passed to the sub:

```
Private Sub label_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   
        lblTest1.Click, lblTest2.Click, lblTest3.Click
    cType(sender, Label).BackColor = Color.Red
End Sub
```

Comment: fast response! thanks a lot, this solved my solution, :)

Answer (score 0):

Same sub can handle events for multiple controls, (Labels) in this case.

So proceed like below:

```
    Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles Label1.Click, Label2.Click, Label3.Click ... 

            Dim myLabel = DirectCast(sender, Label)
            myLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red

        End Sub
```